# What function to use to "crop" a larger SpatRaster with smaller SpatVector?

Tags: r, raster, spatial, terra

I created a `SpatVector` of Illinois and Wisconsin using this code and I downloaded some environmental variables using `FedData`. Downloading NLCD land cover and NED elevation data seemed to work fine but I received an error message while trying to download NLCD canopy cover using this code below...

```
nlcdcanopycover <- get_nlcd(template = ilwi,
                            label = "illwis",
                            year = 2021,
                            dataset = "canopy",
                            extraction.dir = paste0(tempdir("/Users/mduda/OneDrive/G. x billingtonii Research/gbif data/NLCDFedData"), "/FedData/"))

#error message for above No web coverage service at https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/mrlc_download/NLCD_2021_Tree_Canopy_L48/wcs.
#See available services at https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCapabilities
```

I ended up manually downloading canopy cover data from mrlc and ended up with this `SpatRaster` in R which I plotted...
[image]

The only issue is that I only need basically the area of Illinois and Wisconsin. I know there are functions such as `crop`, `merge`, `aggregate`, etc. in `terra` to possibly do this but which one do I use and how do I use the function? I am new to this so non complex answers are appreciated!

Comment: You can use `crop(SpatRaster, SpatVector, mask=TRUE)`

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, for some reason, this did not work either. I received the error message that SpatRaster has no values.

Comment: Without your data it is very hard to help.