# crop SpatRaster has no values after trying to crop SpatRaster to specific SpatVector

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, spatial, terra

I would like to crop some canopy cover data I obtained from mrlc. I downloaded all of the canopy cover data for the United States but I am really only interested in Wisconsin and Illinois. I have a SpatVector of Illinois and Wisconsin borders, `ilwi`

This is `ilwi`

```
 ilwi
 #class       : SpatVector 
 #geometry    : polygons 
 #dimensions  : 2, 6  (geometries, attributes)
 #extent      : -92.8854, -86.96771, 36.98682, 46.95248  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 #coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
 #names       :   FID Program State_Code State_Name Flowing_St FID_1
 #type        : <int>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <int>
 #values      :    14    ACES         IL   ILLINOIS          F   932
 #                 50  WI-ESR         WI  WISCONSIN          F   968
```

I have the canopy cover data cancov as a SpatRaster

```
cancov
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 104424, 161190, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
#extent      : -2493045, 2342655, 177285, 3310005  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : NAD83 / Conus Albers (EPSG:5070) 
#source      : nlcd_tcc_conus_2019_v2021-4.tif 
#color table : 1 
#name        : Layer_1 
#min value   :       0 
#max value   :     254
```

Now, I would like to just get the canopy cover data for Wisconsin and Illinois so I tried the crop function but got an error

```
cropcancov <- crop(cancov, ilwi, mask=TRUE)
#Error: [crop] SpatRaster has no values
```

Also, I am not sure if this is the issue but the coord ref systems are different for the `SpatVector` and `SpatRaster`. Also, I got a warning when I did

```
cancov <- terra::rast("nlcd_tcc_conus_2019_v2021-4.tif") 
#Warning message:
#In class(object) <- "environment" :
# Setting class(x) to "environment" sets attribute to NULL; 
# result will no longer be an S4 object
```

As suggested, I ran this code:

```
pilwi <- project (ilwi, cancov)

pilwi
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 2, 6  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : 242859.9, 730265.2, 1570763, 2673050  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NAD83 / Conus Albers (EPSG:5070) 
# names       :   FID Program State_Code State_Name Flowing_St FID_1
# type        : <int>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <int>
# values      :    14    ACES         IL   ILLINOIS          F   932
#                  50  WI-ESR         WI  WISCONSIN          F   968

crop(cancov, pilwi)
#class       : SpatRaster                  
#dimensions  : 36743, 16247, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
#extent      : 242865, 730275, 1570755, 2673045  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : NAD83 / Conus Albers (EPSG:5070) 
#source      : spat_HGUbU1BYXynbxDC_12144.tif 
#color table : 1 
#name        : Layer_1 
#min value   :       0 
#max value   :     254
```

Answer (score 0):

The SpatRaster and SpatVector should have the same Coordinate Reference System. They do not. The raster has "NAD83 / Conus Albers (EPSG:5070)" whereas the vector has "lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)"

You can project the SpatVector to make them match (avoid projecting raster data if at all possible).

```
library(terra)
cancov <- terra::rast("nlcd_tcc_conus_2019_v2021-4.tif") 
pilwi <- project(ilwi, cancov)
cropcancov <- crop(cancov, pilwi, mask=TRUE)
```

The `In class(object) <- "environment" :` etc warning is not related. It is probably because you are loading an old session into R. That can be fixed with

```
unlink(".RData")
```

And then close R and do not save the session. If you use R-Studio you could do `Session/Terminate R`

Comment: I really appreciate the suggestion. I tried it but it did not work, I still get the same `Error: [crop] SpatRaster has no values` :/ could there be something wrong with the actual data or something?

Comment: I do not think so. Try `plot(cancov); lines(ilwi)`. Do you see the state lines? If so, it should work. If not, you are making a mistake. Also, try 1crop1 without `mask=T`. And make sure you have the current version of "terra"

Comment: I am able to plot cancov, here is a link to a post earlier today (I have been struggling with this all day) with an image of the plotted cancov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475776/what-function-to-use-to-crop-a-larger-spatraster-with-smaller-spatvector?noredirect=1#comment134844970_76475776

Comment: Weirdly, nothing happens when I try `lines(ilwi)` but I am able to plot it and it shows the state outlines of Illinois and Wisconsin. I am not sure if this is what you are referring to though! I just checked for package updates and it looks like terra is not available for an update so I am assuming I have the most current version.

Comment: The error message I receive for `cropcancov <- crop (cancov, ilwi)` is `error: [crop] extents do not ovelap`

Comment: All this suggests that you are not using the projected version of the SpatVector. Can you edit your question, and include the following (and what is returned by it) `pilwi <- project(ilwi, cancov); show(pilwi); crop(cancov, pilwi)`

Comment: Of course - allow me to do that!